# change elements in a list of lists to match a different list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am using Python 2.7 and have a list of lists:

```
my_list_0 = [
    ['X00001', 1123477, 1.25, 'Yes', 'No', 11.53, 3.23, 0.25, 3.0025],
    ['X00002', 1125251, 0.22, 'Yes', 'No', 22.83, 3.6, 0.5, 0.0012],
    ['X00003', 1125433, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 12.0014536],
    ['X00003', 1125435, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 12.0014536],
    ['X00003', 1125436, 966.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.8, 3.8, 0.36, 30.12121],
    ['X00004', 1125437, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 12.0014536],
    ['X00007', 1125438, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 12.0014536],
    ['X00001', 1125439, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 12.0014536],
    ['X00004', 1231254, 1.3, 'Yes', 'No', 21.83, 3.6, 0.5, 1005.000336669],
    ['X00008', 2520250, 54.02, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 82.0000001],
    ['X00005', 3202020, 966.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.8, 3.8, 0.36, 0.000001200012],
    ['X00006', 3215204, 1.36, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.1234565],
    ['X00007', 4561230, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1, 1.1111111],
    ['X00009', 5721365, 1.25, 'No', 'No', 11.53, 3.23, 0.25, 11.1110001],
    ['X00010', 8520525, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1, 20.000156],
    ['X00110', 8520725, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1, 20.000156],
    ['X00010', 8520825, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1, 20.000156],
    ['X00012', 8520123, 966.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.8, 3.8, 0.36, 30.12121],
    ['X00011', 9536122, 54.01, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 15.2312456],
    ['X00015', 1212021, 0.333, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 0],
    ['X00015', 1222221, 0.333, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 0],
    ['X00013', 9654123, 4.1, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 90.01],
    ['X00014', 2021230, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.00001],
    ['X00017', 3322123, 1.23, 'Yes', 'Yes', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12, 0.0002],
    ['X00016', 9531450, 23.15, 'Yes', 'Yes', 1.83, 3.25, 0.12, 30.123],
    ['X00020', 3625252, 1.23, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.02123589],
    ['X00009', 5721777, 1.25, 'No', 'No', 11.53, 3.23, 0.25, 11.1110001],
    ['X00018', 1205203, 1.87, 'Yes', 'No', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12, 89.21233456987],
    ['X00019', 1124521, 0.25, 'No', 'No', 2.1, 0.6, 0.03, 12.564897],
    ['X00021', 8952631, 0.25, 'No', 'No', 2.4, 0.6, 0.03, 23.20033],
    ['X00022', 1123458, 0.33, 'Yes', 'Yes', 10.38, 41.11, 0.5, 0.2314582],
    ['X00023', 3236254, 3, 'No', 'Yes', 10.38, 41.11, 0.5, 78.024568],
    ['X00002', 1205323, 1.87, 'Yes', 'No', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12, 32.021348246],
    ['X00024', 1305324, 1.87, 'Yes', 'No', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12, 32.021348246],
    ['X00025', 1245325, 1.87, 'Yes', 'No', 1.88, 1.25, 1.12, 32.021348246],
    ['X00015', 1212444, 0.333, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 0],
    ['X00015', 1244421, 0.333, 'No', 'No', 1.83, 3.8, 0.01, 0],
    ['X00005', 3332020, 966.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.8, 3.8, 0.36, 0.000001200012],
    ['X00006', 3555204, 1.36, 'Yes', 'No', 1.86, 3.65, 0.15, 0.1234565],
    ['X00007', 9871230, 6.33, 'Yes', 'No', 1.83, 66.22, 0.1, 1.1111111]
]
```

that I am grouping based on the values at index 2 through 8:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

my_list_0_grouped_by = [
    list(z) for _, z in groupby(sorted(my_list_0), itemgetter(2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
]
```

Now I want to re-label the lists based on groups, meaning the 'X00000' label should be replaced with a new one so that each group of lists use the same label.

The new labels are created as a new list (but this is not critical)

```
NEW_LABELS = ['A' + str(i) for i in range(len(my_list_0_grouped_by))]
```

now I want to iterate through my_list_0_grouped_by and replace old 'X00000' label with the new labels from NEW_LABELS, so I do:

```
for i in my_list_0_grouped_by:
    for j in i:
        for k in NEW_LABELS:
            j[0] = k
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as I'm replacing all labels with just the last one from NEW_LABELS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) to do a pair-wise parallel iteration of groups and according labels:

```
for i, k in zip(my_list_0_grouped_by, NEW_LABELS):
    for j in i:
        j[0] = k
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution you provided, work very well on my mock list of list. However I face an issue in my real life data, as the my_list_0_grouped_by turn into a list of tuples. As I'm trying to get the tuples back into lists, I run [[map(list, k) for k in j] for j in my_list_0_grouped_by] however, is not working, Any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use enumerate to get the right label:

```
for index, i in enumerate(my_list_0_grouped_by):
    for j in i:
        j[0] = NEW_LABELS[index]
```

Comment: This can also be written is a more pythonic way using list comprehensions:
`[["A" + str(i)] + l[1:] for i, g in enumerate(my_list_0_grouped_by) for l in g]`

Comment: @Rodrigue But that would do unnecessary extra work for creating the slices (`O(n)`) and the concatenation (`O(n)`)

Comment: You're right, but my point was about the list comprehension. If you are worried about the cost of creating the new list then we could define a function to change the value at index 0 in the original list instead (like you do) and call that from within the comprehension: `l = [rename_group(l, i) for i, g in enumerate(my_list_0_grouped_by) for l in g]`